# sklearn predict_proba not macthing class labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have trained a RandomForestClassifier on my dataset to predict 8 different topics from a body of text. The dataset looks as follows for a given example

```
X_train = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
           [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
          # This is a bag of word

y_train = ["A", "B", "C"] 
# 8 categories in total
```

If I run the following code

```
rdf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
rdf_fitted = rdf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print rdf_fitted.predict(x_test[0])
print rdf_fitted.predict_proba(x_test[0])
print rdf_fitted.classes_
```

I get a strange result

```
["B"]
[0.7, 0.2, 0.1]
["A","B","C"...]
```

Basically, the predicted label ("B" in this case) does not match the `predict_proba` predictions which suggests that "A" has the highest probability.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: when I run your code it works for me. Can you also add your x_test[0] ?

Comment: I have corrected some syntax errors in your code. Unless you post the exact code along with `x_test[0]` what you are using we cant help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this again over the weekend and it now yields the correct result. It seems the issue was caused with a bug in the order at which I executed the code in my Jupyter Notebook. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a mistake I had in my Jupyter Notebook setup